# Azure Mobile authorization error using Google Login

Tags: android, azure

When I try to authorize to Azure Mobile Service using Google+ login with Android, I get error below.

```
com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException:
{"code":401,"error":"Error: Invalid token format. Expected Envelope.Claims.Signature."}
```

My authorize codes are like below.

```
  id_token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken( ParentActivity.this, user_mailAddress,
                                "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" );

                        sharedPrefencesHelper.setActiveMailAddress( user_mailAddress );
//                        sharedPrefencesHelper.setActiveUserName( user_name );
//                        sharedPrefencesHelper.setActiveUserSurname( user_surname );
                        sharedPrefencesHelper.setUserConnectStatement( GOOGLE_CONNECT );

                    } catch ( UserRecoverableAuthException e ) {
                        startActivityForResult( e.getIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN );
                    } catch ( IOException | GoogleAuthException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JsonObject user = new JsonObject();
                    user.addProperty( "id_token", id_token );
                    mClient().login( MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, user, new UserAuthenticationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted( MobileServiceUser user, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response ) {
                            if ( exception == null ) {
                                syncronUserInformations( user_mailAddress );

                            } else {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                                // TODO Azure login olurken bir hata
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                }
```

I completed authorization using facebook, and I am using google play services 7.3.0

Answer (score 0):

An `id_token` can only be obtained by a server side web login. The scope you are using with get you an OAuth token, which is not the same as an `id_token`. To get an `id_token` you need to use a different scope using a web application client ID.

```
// Create 'Client ID for web application' at https://console.developers.google.com
String web_client_id = "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq.apps.googleusercontent.com";

id_token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken( ParentActivity.this, user_mailAddress,
    "audience:server:client_id:" +  web_client_id);
```

The rest of the code should work now that you have an actual `id_token` value.